# window.addEventListener does not work in Word Add-in when called from manifest command (IE11/Edge)

Tags: office-js

I'm developing a Word Add-in and using "ExecuteFunction" to trigger a local storage update. I then have a listener on the window object listening to local storage changes.

The function is triggered and the local storage is updated. However, the event listener is not triggered in the desktop version of Word on Windows.

In the function file (i.e. "FunctionFile" in the manifest), the code is:

```
(() => {
    Office.initialize = () => {
        window['logout'] = (event: Office.AddinCommands.Event) => {
            const localStorageKey = 'local-storage-key';
            let localStorageData = localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey);

            if (localStorageData) {
                localStorageData = JSON.parse(localStorageData);
                localStorageData['isLoggedOut'] = true;
                localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey , JSON.stringify(localStorageData));
            }
            event.completed();
        };
    };
})();
```

Then in the entry point for the app, the code is:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
        try {
            const localStorageKey = 'local-storage-key';
            const localStorageState = localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey);

            // perform some action on local storage update

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

The code works on Word Online, as well as on the Mac version of Word. It does not work in the desktop version of Word on Windows - the `logout` function is executed, but the `storage` event listener is never triggered.

I suspect that the window event listener is not working properly in IE11/Edge - for instance, the app's iframe might not pick up the event triggered by the function file's iframe, or something to that effect.

Is there an alternative/better way to communicate a command executed by a function in the manifest file and the application?

Thanks,

Morgan

Comment: I think your diagnosis is probably correct. The function file runs in an entirely different instance of the browser's JavaScript engine from the task pane, so they have different window objects. I think your task pane is going to have to poll LocalStorage periodically to see if its changed.

Comment: Thanks @RickKirkham. Apparently this is a [known issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/110656/) in IE11 and Edge. LocalStorage updates simply do not work across different tabs/iframes. 

I wonder if the MS team has a workaround for this.

Comment: The only thing which I can tell you from my point of view is once chromium based edge is standardized in all windows build. Then your localstorage event will trigger. Lets hope for the chromium edge as default browser  in all PC's soon

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today with IE11. The workaround for me was to make a polling in tab 1 with setInterval(function() {...}, 1000) to detect a localStorage.setItem(...) made in tab 2. After each unsuccessful iteration with no expected localStorage.getItem(...), make a localStorage.clear() inside {...}. Finally, remember to call clearInterval(...) on successful iteration. An example:

In tab 1:

```
let ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
if (ua.indexOf("MSIE ") != -1 || ua.indexOf('Trident/') != -1 || ua.indexOf('Edge/') != -1) {
    let interval = setInterval(function() {
        checkStorage({ key: "your-local-storage-item-key-set-in-tab-2" }, interval);
        localStorage.clear();
    }, 1000);
} else {
    window.addEventListener("storage", checkStorage);
}
// ...
function checkStorage(event, interval = null) {
    if (event.key == "your-local-storage-item-key-set-in-tab-2") {
        // ...
        let value = localStorage.getItem("your-local-storage-item-key-set-in-tab-2");
        // ...
        if (value) { // or... value == "expected-value"
            // ...
            if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }
}
```

In tab 2:

```
// ...
localStorage.setItem("your-local-storage-item-key-set-in-tab-2", "any-value");
// ...
```

Comment: Hi @Cadu - thanks for the answer. I'd like to give that a try as we still haven't resolved the issue.

How are you able to detect a change in the local storage of tab2 from tab1?

If you're able to provide some sample code that would be great, but in any case this sounds promising.